# Runtime error [abi:cxx11] when compile with g++-4.9 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc4.9, ubuntu-15.10, gcc5

I recently updated Ubuntu from 15.04 to 15.10. One of the major differences between these versions is the update of the default gcc version from gcc-4.9 -> gcc-5. The library I'm developing has been written and compiled for gcc-4.9, and relies on other libraries which only work in gcc-4.9.

I have installed gcc-4.9 onto my computer, and I can successfully compile both the library and my source file. However, when I tried to run the resultant program I get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::ios_base::failure[abi:cxx11]'
what():  basic_ios::clear: iostream error
Aborted (core dumped)`
```

The source code, and the file I'm trying to read here used to work before the upgrade. I have tried using the `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` flag, but I'm not sure this is the right thing to do, also it doesn't work.

This is an example of the flags I'm currently including in my makefile:

```
CPPFLAGS = -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fpermissive -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -std=c++0x -fPIC -MMD -MP
```

Any ideas that might help me out?

Comment: Post your [mcve]​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

You "simply" need to recompile *everything* your program needs that is C++.

See eg [the Debian wiki on the transision](https://wiki.debian.org/GCC5) which has (inter alia)

> The good news is, that GCC 5 now provides a stable libcxx11 ABI, and stable support for C++11 (GCC version before 5 called this supported experimental). This required some changes in the libstdc++ ABI, and now libstdc++6 provides a dual ABI, the classic libcxx98 ABI, and the new libcxx11 (GCC 5 (<< 5.1.1-20) only provides the classic libcxx98 ABI). The bad news is that the (experimental) C++11 support in the classic libcxx98 ABI and the new stable libcxx11 ABIs are not compatible, and upstream doesn't provide an upgrade path except for rebuilding

There is no shortcut.

Comment: Is this also true if I want to continue to use gcc-4.9?

Comment: Well all your system libraries be gcc-5 (and g++-5) compiled as well so it may be hard to avoid.  But yes, but sticking to g++-4.9 (and C system libraries) you can avoid this.

Comment: Okay thanks. Does this explain why when I'm compiling with 4.9 I'm getting the [abi:cxx11] error?

Comment: Is this a joke on recursion?  ;-)   Yes.  As you already asked. And yes, as I tried to answer.   You should be able to replicate with a two-file project, or maybe a single `main()` plus a minimal library.