# libstdc++ error trace unable to understand

Tags: informatica, libstdc++, amazon-linux

I am trying to enable informatica Integration Service which is failing to initialize. The core dump file traces to some libstdc++ error which we are not able to identify.

We have tried to check the libstdc++ version if that is an old version but it points to latest version.

Please see lines #2 through 8.

```
0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
1  0x00007f355b906d41 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
2  0x00007f355c064305 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler () at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:95
3  0x00007f355c061ef6 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=<optimized out>) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:47
4  0x00007f355c061f41 in std::terminate () at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:57
5  0x00007f355c062184 in __cxxabiv1::__cxa_throw (obj=obj@entry=0x7f353c042e70, tinfo=0x7f355c34e368 <typeinfo for std::ios_base::failure[abi:cxx11]>, dest=0x7f355c094a30 <std::ios_base::failure[abi:cxx11]::~failure()>) at ../../../../libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:93
6  0x00007f355c08cea3 in std::__throw_ios_failure (__s=__s@entry=0x7f355c115f67 "basic_ios::clear") at ../../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/ios.cc:50
7  0x00007f355c0cb54d in std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::clear (this=<optimized out>, __state=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-7.3.1-20180303/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_ios.tcc:48
8  0x00007f355c0d00aa in std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::setstate (__state=<optimized out>, this=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-7.3.1-20180303/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_ios.h:158
9  std::istream::_M_extract<unsigned int> (this=0x7f3543ffe440, __v=@0x7f3543ffe85c: 0) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-7.3.1-20180303/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/x86_64-redhat-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/istream.tcc:114
10 0x00007f3565c90266 in PmProcessStatsManager::fetchCPUStats() () from /obin/informatica/10.2/server/bin/libpmuti.so
11 0x00007f3565c90e59 in PmProcessStatsManager::collect() () from /obin/informatica/10.2/server/bin/libpmuti.so
12 0x00007f3565c9168a in PmMetricsCollector::collect() () from /obin/informatica/10.2/server/bin/libpmuti.so
13 0x00007f35660145a5 in SFOSMonitor::doMonitorProcesses() () from /obin/informatica/10.2/server/bin/libpmsf.so
14 0x00007f3566014e98 in SFOSMonitor::runImpl() () from /obin/informatica/10.2/server/bin/libpmsf.so
15 0x00007f356601caf8 in SFRunnable::run() () from /obin/informatica/10.2/server/bin/libpmsf.so
16 0x00007f356601cb81 in SFRunnable::run(void*) () from /obin/informatica/10.2/server/bin/libpmsf.so
17 0x00007f3562498a35 in ACE_Thread_Adapter::invoke_i() () from /obin/informatica/10.2/server/bin/libACE.so.6.3.3
18 0x00007f3562498ab1 in ACE_Thread_Adapter::invoke() () from /obin/informatica/10.2/server/bin/libACE.so.6.3.3
19 0x00007f3566c7354b in start_thread (arg=0x7f3543fff700) at pthread_create.c:465
20 0x00007f355b9c62ff in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

Comment: I believe this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158934/runtime-error-abicxx11-when-compile-with-g-4-9-on-ubuntu-15-10

Comment: we are using gcc7 with libstdc++ . Not a fullblown developer but any hints if i need to install new gcc or libstdc libraries

Comment: could you please check 1. the $PATH or $LIBPATH are properly set with Infa binaries. Check the Ubuntu and Infa 10 compatibility too. Also check if the user is able to access those lib files. Informatica should be able to pickup all necessary lib files.